# Prototype-inherited properties not reactive in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this code. It's purely for experimental purposes :

**test.html**

```
<div id="example-1">
    {{ stuff.dosobject.notlist }}
    <button v-on:click="dostuff">DO STUFF</button>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

**test.js**

```
var oneobject={
        dosobject:{
            notlist:"foo"  
        }
    }

var stuff = Object.create(oneobject)

var example1 = new Vue({
  el: '#example-1',
  data: {
    stuff:stuff
  },
  methods:
  {
      dostuff:function(event)
      {
          if(stuff.dosobject.notlist=="foo")
              stuff.dosobject.notlist="bar"
          else
              stuff.dosobject.notlist="foo"
      }
  }
})
```

The object `stuff` is created with `oneobject` as a prototype.
I would expect the property `stuff.dosobject.notlist` to be reactive, ie the `{{ stuff.dosobject.notlist }}` part of the template to be re-rendered when the button is clicked.

It doesn't seem to be the case.

Am I doing something wrong ? Or is it normale VueJS behavior?

After thinking a bit about it, It would not seem so weird to not make all prototype properties reactive because the prototype chain can be quite long and cause performance issues.

Comment: Would you expect Vue to detect changes to, say,  `Object.prototype`?

Comment: From the [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data): "_**The object must be plain**: native objects such as browser API objects and prototype properties are ignored_."

Comment: Just do: stuff: oneobject

Comment: @destoryer : Well, indeed it's rather clear in the doc, I had missed it. 
I wouldn't expect Vue to monitor Object.prototype changes no, but I would have like to be able to organize objects in my data-model in a object-oriented fashion. Nonetheless, I get that it's difficult to decide where to draw the line in the prototype chain for reactivity, so I understand that design decision. Might be that my way of thinkin about the data model is not optimized yet

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the way you'd get around these types of reactivity caveats is to use [`Vue.set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set):

> Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is
> also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add new
> properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal property
> additions (e.g. `this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi'`).

However, `Vue.set` contains the following check:

> https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/4f81b5db9ab553ca0abe0706ac55ceb861344330/src/core/observer/index.js#L212-L215
>
> ```
> if (key in target && !(key in Object.prototype)) {
>  target[key] = val
>  return val
> }
> ```

I've read and re-read [Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html), which states:

> When you pass a **plain** JavaScript object to a Vue instance ... (emphasis mine)

So it seems clear you should not be passing complicated objects and expect reactivity to work. However, prototypical inheritance is part of "plain" objects, and when you're working with classes, 3rd party libraries, or large, complicated code-bases, dealing with "non-plain" objects passed as props or data is sometimes unavoidable.

It would be nice to "make reactive" existing objects via use of `Vue.set`, but because of the `in` check, it won't copy the prototype value to the object and set up the reactive getter/setter pair on it.

Here are two solutions you can try:

1. Clone the object instead of inheriting from it, ensuring `stuff` has `dosobject` as an [own property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
2. Trigger [`$forceUpdate`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate) when you set any property on `stuff`, or create a [proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/dpocs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) for `stuff` to do it automatically in a `set` trap.

---

In an edge case we encountered, we set up a function to ensure changes we set are picked up by Vue's reactivity system:

```js
function setPropertyReactive(obj, key, value) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    obj[key] = value;
    return;
  }

  delete Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)[key];
  Vue.set(obj, key, value);
}
```